# Instance Methods: complex numbers

Tags: java, eclipse, math

I am currently doing solo text book work for java(not part of a class) and I'm stuck on a question.

Write an instance method modulus for this class that could be called by a statement like
double size = z.modulus(); where z is of type Complex. If z represented the value a + ib,
then the call would set the variable size to the value of |z| = square root(a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup>).

What am I doing wrong?

```
public class complex {  
    double re;
    double im;
    complex x;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    public complex z = new complex();
    {
        z.im = In.getDouble();
        z.re = In.getDouble();      
    }
    //public complex modulus = (x);
    //{
    //  x.im = z.im * z.im;
    //  x.re = z.re * z.re;
    //  return ;
    //}

    public double size() {
        System.out.println(Math.sqrt(x.im+ x.re));
        return Math.sqrt(x.im+ x.re);       
    }

    double size = z.modulus();
    //  {
    //}

    private double modulus() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        x.im = z.im * z.im;
        x.re = z.re * z.re;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I made the changes and came out with this but it still doesn't work i put the errors next to the line in which they occur.

```
public class complex {
double re;
double im;

public complex z = new complex();
{
    z.im = In.getDouble();
    z.re = In.getDouble();}
public static void main(String[] args) {



private double modulus() {    // insert enumIdentifier and body, Syntax error on "double" @ expected.

    return Math.sqrt( im * im + re * re );
}

double size = z.modulus();


}

}
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong? Errors? Exceptions? Wrong output?

Comment: @Takendarkk   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at complex.<init>(complex.java:30)

Comment: @Liste1134 Based on your comment it looks like inside your `complex` constructor you are creating new instance of `complex`, which means you are invoking `complex` constructor again (which again creates its own another `complex` instance, which means it calls constructor, which creates instance, which calls constructor,... and so on). It looks like it is caused by this field `public complex z = new complex();`.

Comment: Please remove the extraneous code and comments

Comment: The code you have posted does not compile.  It may be missing some curly braces.  It's hard to tell what's going on because the posted code appears to be written by someone with a very confused understanding of Java syntax, but the posted code apparently isn't what you're actually compiling.  Please use copy-and-paste to post the _exact_ code that's giving you an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to refer to either `x` or `z`.  You have the right fields in your class to be able to calculate the modulus.

```
public double modulus() {
    return Math.sqrt( im * im + re * re );
}
```

However, in the code in your question, you seem to be defining your class's methods inside the `main` method.  You can't do that.  Close off the definition of one method (with `}`) before starting the next.

Comment: You can also use [`Math.hypot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#hypot-double-double-).

Comment: @ajb Ooh, good point.  But I'm not going to change my answer, because I think this way, OP might understand better what's going on.

Comment: @DavidWallace This helped a lot but I'm still having errors so I made an update to the question with the new code and it's errors

Comment: Well, in your updated question, you're still trying to define a method _inside_ your `main` method.  And you're trying to use something called `In`, which you haven't defined anywhere.

Comment: So do I move the modulus part out of the main method too? also "In" is a separate class from copied from the textbook that takes user input like numbers and string.

Comment: Looks like i finally got it to work though it doesn't say anything and the console is blank. Thank you